# Call a function of a controller from index.html/appController.js using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app where the navigation, header, footer etc. are directly into the index.html. The problem is that in the navigation there is a tab called notifications and I have a new requirement that it should contain the number of notifications. Ex:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
        <a data-ui-sref="allNotifications">Notifications {{amount}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The functions I need are in `allNotificationsController.js`

```
$scope.getNotifications = function() {
    ...
    return notifications; //returns array
}
```

The easiest way is to DOM edit the length of the array, however it will only happen when I'm in the page that belongs to the controller. I want the notifications to be visible all the time. Is there any way to call the function directly from `index.html` or the root controller (`app.controller.js`) without rewriting all the logic?

Comment: *without rewriting all the logic?* - but it should be rewritten. There likely should be a service that stores notifications, then any controller can access it.

Comment: Initially these notifications were shown only on the allNotifications page. I can write a service to handle notifications, but I'm curious if there's some sort of a 'hack' to get that functionality working while I'm refactoring.

Comment: It's unclear from the question where the data is stored, that's what matters. Consider providing http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you need *anything* in more than one place and it's the same thing (it only needs instantiation once per app run) it should sit in a `.service()` and it should be injected into the controllers/components/modules where you need it. Not only it is available anywhere, but it also is updated everywhere, so all changes are instantly updated, as it's the same object. In fact, best practice is to put anything that is *"the same in all app"* into a service, even if you use it one place only. This ensures that whenever you will need it in another place you just inject it and you're done.

Comment: Ok, you guys convinced me, I'll focus my efforts on doing it the right way by moving the functionality into a service instead of looking for a temporary workaround :)